# delayed_job - Stop only one process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Using `delayed_job` gem, how can I stop only one process without stopping all the workers?

For example:

`rake jobs:work` start workers

`process1 = SomeClass.enqueue` start process 1 in code

`process2 = SomeClass.enqueue` start process 2 in code

`process1.stop` will stop only process 1 and keep process 2 running.

I guess a similar question would be "How can I get the PID of a delayed job process?" because then I can kill the process using the PID.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @utiq Yes, I just used the `whenever` gem which uses cron jobs. But I'm open to the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Delayed Job on a whole is a process. To know the pid check the .pid file that is created in temp folder when delayed job starts.
In order to stop one particular process from code use Delayed::Job.all, or find your job and use the destroy method to close it.